# Prove $|u|^p + |u|^q \leq K |u|^{max\{p,q\}}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $ 0 \leq p,q < \infty$, and $u$ a continuous function, prove
$$|u|^p + |u|^q \leq K |u|^{max(p,q)}$$
$K$ may depend on the supremum of $u$, but actually the small values of $u$ give the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If u is a function without any further constraints, I don't think this is true. For example take
$$ u(t) = t^2,\, p=2, \, q=1$$
We have that

$$t^{4} + t^{2} \le Kt^{4}, \,\,\, \forall t\in \mathbb{R}$$

(I dropped the modulus as $t^2\ge 0$).
Divide by $t^{2}$ (which we can do if we assume $t\ne 0$):

$$ (K-1)t^2 -1 \ge 0$$

Now, K-1 needs to be positive, so we can take $a>0$ s.t. $a^2 = K-1$, giving the following inequality:

$$ (at)^2 -1 \ge 0 $$

Which is true only if $|t|\ge \frac{1}{a}$, thus providing a counterexample for your statement as we cannot find a fixed $K$ that satisfies it for all $t$.

So unless $u$ is guaranteed to be $\ge \epsilon$ around 0 I don't think you'll find such $K$, or maybe there are some other conditions that are missing in the questions?